# fix position in a div css

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

I'm a new to css and i really can't fix all as i want...
How can i align vertical the h1 to the start of user form?
but most important problem for me is that i can't center good the check and the link, i want it one below the other and centered in the div.
I'm not sure if i have positioned good the div but i want it centred but not too low on the page.
thanks to everyone!

```css
body {
    text-align: left;
    background-image: url("img/lemon.jpg");
    color: #1b1b1b;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password]{
    width: 65%;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid darkgray;
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    resize: vertical;
}

h1 {
    font-size: x-large;
}
h2 {
    font-size: x-large;
}

button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 7px 20px;
    width: 65%;
    height: 20%;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3d94f6 5%, #1e62d0 100%);
    background-color: #3d94f6;
    border: 1px solid #337fed;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 17px;

    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: -1px 1px 1px #1570cd;
}

button:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e62d0 5%, #3d94f6 100%);
    background-color: #1e62d0;
}

button:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}

.container {
    width: 35%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 7%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 11px rgb(11, 11, 11);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 11px rgb(11, 11, 11);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 11px rgb(11, 11, 11);
    overflow: hidden;
}

#check {
    display:block;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

span.frgt {
    margin-top: 7px;
    display: block;  
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1e62d0;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="uname" required>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="psw" required>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <hr>
        <label id="check">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
        </label>
        <span class="frgt">forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the h1 to the same width of the button and use "margin: 0 auto" to center it, this will make the h1 span the width of the button, and by default the text will be left aligned to the start of the button.

```
h1 {
  font-size: x-large;
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I'm not too sure exactly what you want to do with the check section. If you use "text-align: center", this will center it, or use the same code as above to align it with the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `text-align: center;` and `vertical-align:top;`

If your problem still exists, please explain more clearly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier to align your elements, just wrap them into one div and adjust the div with CSS instead of dealing with each single element.

Here is an example of what you can do.

```css
body {
  text-align: left;
  background-image: url("img/lemon.jpg");
  color: #1b1b1b;
}

.form {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
}

.form-bottom {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid darkgray;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  resize: vertical;
}

h1 {
  font-size: x-large;
}

h2 {
  font-size: x-large;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px 20px;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3d94f6 5%, #1e62d0 100%);
  background-color: #3d94f6;
  border: 1px solid #337fed;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: -1px 1px 1px #1570cd;
}

button:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e62d0 5%, #3d94f6 100%);
  background-color: #1e62d0;
}

button:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

.container {
  width: 35%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 7%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 11px rgb(11, 11, 11);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 11px rgb(11, 11, 11);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 11px rgb(11, 11, 11);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#check {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

span.frgt {
  margin-top: 7px;
  display: block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1e62d0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="uname" required>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="psw" required>
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-bottom">
      <label id="check">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
          </label>
      <span class="frgt">forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align: center;` to center text within container.